# Campus navigation:Getting the navmesh agent to move to desired building while ignoring other buildings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation

I'm trying to create a 3d campus navigation system using the A* algorithm. I'm currently having two problems. First, I only know how to make one building as the target destination, I don't know how to include the other buildings. Secondly, when my NPC starts to move to it's target, it passes through the building and not around it. I used the Navmesh obstacle component but I don't get what I want because in order to follow the shortest path, I have a building that when traversed through, grants the shortest path to that destination and that's what I want my NPC to do. Please help. I'm stuck

Comment: How are your buildings made? Are they solid blocks or a bunch of walls or what. There are lots of tutorials on navmesh.

Comment: BugFinder. Sorry for not replying earlier. my buildings were modeled in blender and then dragged into unity

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get the NPC to pass through. Although i had to divide the building into two parts and assign different NavMesh Obstacles to each of them which gave way for the NPC.Now i just created a dropdown list and i also made all the buildings into an array. The buildings are all labelled according to their several locations in the campus. i want to make it in such a way that the dropdown shows the list of names in the array and when i click on each name(building),it sets the NPC's target destination to the position of that particular building. I've been trying to google it but i always end up at a dead end. Any ideas?